# Why do we write second derivatives like $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$

Tags: notation, derivatives

Why do we write the second derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$ as $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$?

It's never been explained to me, and I've never found a particularly good explanation. What's up with this weird derivative notation?

Answer (score 5):

One derivation goes as follows,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d}{dt}(x)\right) \to \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) \to \frac{d\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)}{dt} \to \frac{ddx}{dtdt} \to \frac{d^2x}{(dt)^2} \to \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}.$$

Comment: A more conscise derivation is found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Notation

Comment: Also, it's always good to remember that sometimes we treat Leibniz's infinitesimals like quotients, but they really aren't.

Comment: This makes very little sense to me. How come we can separate the $d$ from $x$ in $dx$, but we can't separate the $d$ from $t$ in $dt$? What are these $d$ things anyway, and why do we treat the one attached to $x$ differently from the one attached to $t$?